# "Buffer exceeds maximum allowed size" error while starting debug on a Java ME project

Tags: java, java-me, intellij-idea

I have `IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.3` and `Java ME platform SDK 3.0.5` installed. I have created a Java ME project from scratch, with the only class, which extends *MIDlet*. My run/debug configuration uses the *DefaultCldcPhone1* as a device emulator.

When I try to run/debug the application, I get this:

```
Fatal Error: Buffer exceeds maximum allowed size (4096)
```

**Any ideas why is this happening?**

**UPD1:** So far I have figured out that this is not related to the IDE, because copy-pasting the same command to the command prompt gives the same result (unless, of course, the %MY_MODULE_NAME%.jar is generated improperly).

**UPD2:** I have shortened the command manually (removed the classpath completely, excluding my jar) and it worked as expected. I don't understand, where this limitation comes from? I'm on Windows 7, if that matters.

The run command IDEA produces (line breaks added by me, total length is **3757** symbols):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\bin\emulator" 
-classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\agui_1.0.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\cdc_1.0.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\cdc_1.1.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\cldc_1.0.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\cldc_1.1.1.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\cldc_1.1.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\fp_1.0.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\fp_1.1.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\jsr082_1.1.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\jsr120_1.1.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\jsr135_1.2.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\jsr172_1.0-base.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\jsr172_1.0-xmlrpc.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\jsr172_1.0.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\jsr177_1.0-apdu.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\jsr177_1.0-crypto.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\jsr177_1.0-jcrmi.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\jsr177_1.0-pki.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\jsr177_1.0.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\jsr179_1.0.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\jsr180_1.1.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\jsr184_1.1.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\jsr205_2.0.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\jsr211_1.0.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\jsr226_1.0.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\jsr229_1.1.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\jsr234_1.0.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\jsr238_1.0.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\jsr239_1.0.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\jsr253_1.0.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\jsr256_1.2.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\jsr257_1.0.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\jsr258_1.0.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\jsr280_1.0.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\jsr281_1.0.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\jsr287_1.0.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\jsr293_1.0.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\jsr75_1.0.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\midp_1.0.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\midp_2.0.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\midp_2.1.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\pbp_1.0.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\pbp_1.1.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\pp_1.0.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\pp_1.1.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5\lib\secop_1.0.jar;
%MY_PROJECT_FOLDER%\%MY_MODULE_NAME%.jar" 
"-Xdescriptor:C:\Users\%MY_USERNAME%\.IntelliJIdea11\system\caches\temp5962107910134648248.jad" 
-Xdebug 
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=61127,server=y 
-Xdevice:DefaultCldcPhone1
```

Comment: Does it help if you move J2ME SDK from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5` to `c:\j2me` and use it from there so that the generated classpath is shorter?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've done a similar thing, check the UPD2.

Comment: @CrazyCoder In other words, yes, it does.

Comment: IDEA is trying to push all midp jars in classpath, but I don't think it's necessary

Comment: I cleaned up the classpath by removing all JSRs. Everything works fine now (with a couple of tweaks, nothing general). I don't like this solution, though. What if I want all those JSRs? What do I do then?